# WordPress: Force Republish Posts to Update Content

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm currently working on a custom post type using ACF. Essentially, you fill out a form and upon submission, it creates a new post and the details are then visible via shortcode in a map. Each submission uses it's own shortcode, in it's own popup that appears on the map (i.e. `[shortcode post_id=1]`)

The problem I'm having is that upon submission, the shortcode fails to pick up the data that I've just submitted. When I check the post on the backend, all of the fields are filled in. If I then press the update button on the backend, the data will appear in the shortcode as normal. Is there any way to automatically get this working?

I've tried several things, such as enabling the REST API on ACF, adding an extra `save_post` action to try and resave and update the content.

Here's the current script handling my saves:

```php
// create saving post function
function my_acf_save_interactive_map_post( $post_id ) {

    // exit based on certain conditions
    if( get_post_type($post_id) !== 'interactive_map' ) {   
      return;
    }
    if( is_admin() ) {   
      return;   
    }
    // get post variables
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    // set post category
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $category_id = get_term_by('slug', $category, 'interactive_map_category')->term_id;
    wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $category_id, 'interactive_map_category', true);
    
    // get map values
    $map_key = get_field_key('geek_im_map');
    $map_values = $_POST['acf'][$map_key];
    $map_values_array = json_decode(str_replace('\\', '', $map_values), true);

    if(!empty($map_values_array)) {
      // create longitude and latitude variables from map
      $longitude = $map_values_array['lng'];
      $latitude = $map_values_array['lat'];
      // update longitude and latitude values
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'geek_im_geolocation_geek_im_longitude', $longitude);
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'geek_im_geolocation_geek_im_latitude', $latitude);
    }

    error_log(print_r($post, true));

    // update post information
    $title = ucwords($map_values_array['address']) . '(' . $post_id . ')';
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'geek_im_info_geek_im_title', $title);
    $content = '<div>[geek_interactive_map_display post_id="' . $post_id . '"]</div>';
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'geek_im_info_geek_im_content', $content);

    // custom function found in acf-submission-handler.php
    post_custom_data($post_id, $category, $_POST);
}

// add action for saving post
add_action('acf/pre_save_post', 'my_acf_save_interactive_map_post', 5, 1);
```

And then an extra function to attempt to update the post again.

```php
// create update post function
function my_acf_update_interactive_map_content( $post_id ) {
    // exit based on certain conditions
    if( get_post_type($post_id) !== 'interactive_map' ) {   
      return;
    }
    if( is_admin() ) {   
      return;   
    }
    // get post variables
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // force post update
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'my_acf_update_interactive_map_content');
    wp_update_post(array("ID" => $post_id));
    add_action( 'save_post', 'my_acf_update_interactive_map_content');
}

// add action for updating post
add_action('save_post', 'my_acf_update_interactive_map_content');
```

I've tried various different methods, but can't seem to work out why it isn't grabbing the data properly. It's all already stored on the post page when I check the backend, but the values are only collected when I manually press the "Update" button. I just want it to immediately update with the data it has already. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should not use `update_post_meta`, to update ACF field values. Use the function ACF provides, `update_field`.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I didn't ever encounter that in my research. After rejigging everything to use this method, it's all started to fit together. Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @CBroe in the comments on my post, the solution is to replace `update_post_meta` with `update_field`, which is an ACF function. As well as this, it tends to be better to update using the field key rather than the field name. Or if you're using groups (like I am) you can update the field name onto the name of the group.

For example, if you have a field called "field" and a group called "group". You would target the field by updating "group_field".